# Multi-tenancy with Bootstrap and LESS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, multi-tenant

My company has a large code base and we recently started implementing bootstrap (v3.3.4).

We have 100+ clients that all run through the same website, using a url like `https://www.company.com/{client}/home/index`.

We use the `{client}` part of the url to identify the client, and apply their specific settings and styles that make the site look and run differently, as if it's their own site. We currently only allow ~20 clients to have custom styles, but that might change in the near future.

When we initially implemented bootstrap we wanted to keep the core bootstrap styles (`bootstrap-common.css`) that are common to all clients separate from the client-specific bootstrap styles (`bootstrap-client1.css`, `bootstrap-client2.css`).

This was a good idea for caching purposes and because changes to the less in `bootstrap-common.css` would not cause all of the client-specific less files to be recompiled. However, it was problematic because if we wanted to do something simple like override `@brand-primary` for a client, we had to not only override the variable in `bootstrap-client1.less` but since it was compiled separately from `bootstrap-common.less` we had to override all of the css from `bootstrap-common.less` that used that variable. Major code duplication and a maintenance nightmare.

We have since switched to having each client have their own compiled bootstrap css file that includes all of bootstrap, our common overrides and styles, and the client-specific overrides and styles.

This solves the problem of overriding bootstrap variables and having the core bootstrap compiled with those overrides included. This means all we have to do in the client less file is set the `@brand-primary` variable, and bootstrap will use that variable everywhere.

However, it isn't good for caching because the core/common boostrap styles aren't separated out into it's own css file. If you switch between clients, or you change anything in the common or client less, a new file has to be downloaded, instead of having separate files that can be cached individually. Also, if you make one change in the core/common less files, every single client less file has to be recompiled.

I'm new to bootstrap and less, and after doing some research I haven't been able to find anyone with this same use case. Does anyone know of a good/standard way to handle this situation?

Comment: I use bootstrap already compiled (_and I never modify it - updating bootstrap will be easier in the future_), and I make my own SCSS (or LESS if you prefer) to make a personalized look that overrides bootstrap where I needed. My own css must be loaded after bootstrap. _In your case  you should just create personalized css for each client and don't even modify bootstrap as main framework_.

Comment: @MacKentoch Ok so how would I override a certain color that is used everywhere in bootstrap, so that it is different for each client?

Comment: To **create my own** css **I start from a `SASS bootstrap`** (or **`LESS bootstrap`) and clean it to just **keep only what I need to overwrite**. As you use `LESS`, manage just with variables. Ex : Colors-client 1 : compile css name it client1, then colors Clients2 : compile css, then name it clients2 etc...

Comment: This is my way, but I don't have to create tons of custom css like you may have. so maybe my solution is not the best in your case. Maybe you save time with customizer [getbootsrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Comment: @MacKentoch I don't have to create tons of custom css. It just makes sense that you would want different theme colors for each client. Thus it would be easiest to just have to override a variable like `@brand-primary` and have bootstrap use that variable everywhere, so you don't have to override any css.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a closer look to the `bootstrap.less` file. The contents of this file will show you how Bootstrap's modularization has been set up.

Bootstrap enables you to use not some components / modules by commenting them out in the `bootstrap.less`. All components and modules require `variables.less` (but possible do not need all variable). Variables such as `@brand-primary` are used (indirectly) in most components and modules so changing them requires to recompile most of your code too.

Notice that `@brand-primary` sets many other variables too:

```
./variables.less:@brand-primary:         darken(#428bca, 6.5%); // #337ab7
./variables.less:@link-color:            @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@component-active-bg:       @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@btn-primary-bg:                 @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@pagination-active-bg:                 @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@pagination-active-border:             @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@label-primary-bg:            @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@progress-bar-bg:             @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@panel-primary-border:        @brand-primary;
./variables.less:@panel-primary-heading-bg:    @brand-primary;
```

For your use case to should find out which components and modules to use and which of them depend on variables which can be changed by your client.

For your bootstrap-common.css can can possible use something like that shown below:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";
@import "glyphicons.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "code.less";
@import "grid.less";

//custom Code
```

Whilst `bootstrap-client1.less` then will look as follows:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "client_variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Core CSS
@import "tables.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components
@import "component-animations.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "button-groups.less";
@import "input-groups.less";
@import "navs.less";
@import "navbar.less";
@import "breadcrumbs.less";
@import "pagination.less";
```

In the above the `client_variables.less` file contains the client's overrides. The bootstrap-common.css file can now be used for all your clients and cached.

I hope this helps, although i do realize that it is not perfect.

Bootstrap components itself can not be compiled be splitting them into core and style. For instance buttons have a base classes and styles classes, but both the base classes and the style classes are compiled from the same file (less/buttons.less).

You should also read: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73875782